# Why the Breusch-Pagan rejects H0 on apparently non-heteroskedastic data?

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals, breusch-pagan

Breusch-Pagan rejects the H0 on this residuals:

```
> length(model$residuals)
[1] 515959
> summary(model$residuals)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-205.000   -4.420   -0.451    0.000    4.130  196.000 
> quantile(model$residuals, seq(0, 1, 1/10))
         0%         10%         20%         30%         40%         50%         60%         70%         80%         90%        100% 
-205.228344  -10.137559   -5.705923   -3.400891   -1.814776   -0.450546    1.036849    2.914375    5.648389   10.733350  196.011350 
> bptest(model)

    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  model
BP = 1385.57, df = 14, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
```

Looking at the residuals variance with @whuber [visualization function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33028/measures-of-residuals-heteroscedasticity) I don't see any heteroskedasticity issue:

[image: ResidualsvsPredicted]

So yes, there are some extreme observations at the tail of distribution, but is this enough to reject the H0?

**Manual Breusch-Pagan test**

```
summary(lm(I(model$residuals^2) ~ data$X1 + data$X2 + data$data$X3 + data$X4))

Call:
lm(formula = I(model$residuals^2) ~ data$X1 + data$X2 + 
    data$dataX3 + data$X4)

Residuals:

   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
  -356   -100    -79    -23  41965 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           176.52       4.82   36.66 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
data$X1                -5.21       0.28  -18.60 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
data$X2               -75.36       4.75  -15.88 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
data$X3                15.70       0.85   18.48 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
data$X4fact2           10.84       3.15    3.44              0.00059 ***
data$X4fact3            1.14       2.15    0.53              0.59735    
data$X4fact4           96.31       6.98   13.80 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
data$X4fact5          191.39      12.73   15.04 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
data$X4fact6            3.44       4.03    0.85              0.39280    
data$X4fact7            8.30       2.79    2.97              0.00298 ** 
data$X4fact8           19.38       2.66    7.29     0.00000000000031 ***
data$X4fact9            1.44       2.37    0.61              0.54468    
data$X4fact10          46.35      11.19    4.14     0.00003435124602 ***
data$X4fact11          -6.23       2.71   -2.30              0.02168 *  
data$X4fact12          18.07       3.46    5.22     0.00000017455269 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 502 on 515944 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.00269,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.00266 
F-statistic: 99.2 on 14 and 515944 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002
```

Comment: You seem to have quite a high N, right? This may just be a consequence of the fact that with a sufficiently large N, *any* deviation from H0 will get significant. I'd assume that, for instance, the large number of residuals clustered around -200 should "not happen" under normality.

Comment: Yes, N is 1/2 million, I added it to the code.

Comment: Well. Using a SD of 6 (to roughly match your 1st and 3rd quartile), R gives me a probability of seeing a single -200 of 6.35e-244. You seem to have at least 15 or 20 residuals of -200. It seems like your tails are simply *way* too heavy to be expected from a normal distribution. Combine that with your large N, and *any* normality test will likely reject. You may be better served with the question whether you really need normality at all, given your huge N.

Comment: Why the bptest would fail if the $Y$ observations are not normally distributed? I don't see how that relates to the residuals. And even if the *residuals* are not normally distributed, why a bptest would fail to reject? I don't think homoskedasticity implies a normal distribution...

Comment: You are right. The problem probably rather is that the -200 residuals cluster at low fitted values.

Comment: Well in the meantime I excluded all $Y$ observations outside [-80, 80] and BP still doesn't reject. I think the problem is the large sample size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to see what happened is to perform BP by hand, e.g. as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test).

As you regress the squared residual on your predictors, you will be able to learn what particular predictor explains variance in residuals and whether there is any practical significance. E.g., if R-squared is 0.001, then it looks like the test has too much power due to a large sample size. Also, it may be the case that it's enough to delete a few outliers to make it go away, which may be preferable to doing WLS. Finally, if you do WLS you may find out that the results are virtually the same as if you ignored BP test altogether.

Comment: I added the manual BP test to the question.

Comment: With R-squared well below 1%, it looks like you don't have to adjust for heteroskedasticity. I bet that even if you run WLS, the p-values and all will remain virtually the same.

Comment: ok, but why the test doesn't reject then?

Comment: As Stephan guessed correctly, the problem is your huge sample size. It has the same problem as the normality tests described here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2498/54099

Comment: For the same reason, you can't rely just on the p-values in your original regression because even tiny p-values may have little practical significance. In addition, try looking at the partial R-squareds.

Comment: ok. For clarity, your last comment is not related to the BP test specifically right?

Comment: The last comment is related to the original regression. Even in a homoskedastic case, you can get covariates that are practically insignificant but have very small p-values because of the sample size.

Comment: So I guess this answer is: because the BP test will find a significant, albeit very small $R^2$, due to the high statistical power (very large data set)?

Comment: My answer is: one doesn't have to adjust for heteroskedasticity here because it's not practically significant.

Comment: Pratically significant? What does that mean? I think the key is the low $R^2$ in the BP.

Comment: Right, in this case we used R-squared to measure practical significance, but we could have used something else.

Comment: Like what? What else gives a quantitative measure of practicality for the BP test?

Comment: In general, the question is how much better the variance model can predict variance compared to just assuming the constant variance. E.g., one could use some kind of out-of-sample prediction error instead of R-squared. However, in this case the sample is so large that in-sample performance should be close to out-of-sample performance, so using R-squared is fine.